# How we can convert the date format from DDMMMYYYY to YYYYMMDD in XSLT 2.0 . Example 31122007 To 20071231

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement to convert the date from DDMMYYYY to YYYYMMDD using XSLT2.0. Here the date i usually get from the XML with DDMMYYYY format which i need to change to YYYYMMDD format. How can we do this please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Either the way Adarsh suggests, or

```
replace(yourdate, '(..)(..)(....)', '$3$2$1')
```

I'm really surprised to see questions like this on StackOverflow. What part of this problem is difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(yourdate,5,4),substring(yourdate,3,2),substring(yourdate,1,2))"/>
```